# How to get the public URL and download the directory from google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, file-handling

I have some files and a **directory** in my `GCP storage`, from it I know how to access my files in python using the **public URL**.

I did it this way...

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
file_object=open("model.pkl", 'wb')
file_object.write(r.content)
```

But I am not able to find any direct public URL to my directory. As well as don't know how to download either a directory or zip using that URL.

Would be much appreciated if the solution is in `Python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Simply because the directory doesn't exist on Cloud Storage. All the file are stored at the / of the buket, and the fully qualified name of the objects contains the /path/to/object.

By convention, and for better human readability, Google Cloud console split the / in "directory" for the presentation. But the directory haven't physical existence. Delete the /path/to/object file and the directories path disappear.

Review and rethink your app and design accordingly.